# How to obtain field names of RSS feed(xml file) in python dynamically using feedparser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rss

I have used feedparser library in python to read rss feeds from particlar URL. 
the feeds are received in 'fee' variable by using following line of code:

```
fee =  feedparser.parse('http://www.indiatimes.com/r/python/.rss')
```

`fee` contains feed in list of list format. The format and the data we get in this is complex and not fixed.

I want to obtain names of fields(keys) of this RSS feed dynamically. How to do that?

some field names are fixed such as link, date etc. But I need names of all fields in my code.

Comment: You should take a look at this link:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/feedparser/using-feedparser-in-python

Comment: thanks. But I have already gone thorough this link. The problem is in obtaining those key names e.g. print d.entries[0]['link'] , in this 'entries' and 'link' is not there in compusoryly in every feed(xml) file. And I need those names dynamically I am not aware in advance which field names I am obtaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
feeds_all =  feedparser.parse('http://www.indiatimes.com/r/python/.rss')
```

I am not sure what kind of json it is, but the functions `.keys()` and `.values()` work fine on it. What I did is, for dynamically getting names of keys that are previously unknown (above answer gives static keys and it's values, you need to know the key names in advance), `fee.keys()` and it worked!

So, the answer is in the following lines: `channel_keys = feeds_all.keys()` and `feed_keys = feeds_all.feed.keys()`, for getting value of those keys, `feed_values = feeds_all.feed.values()`....

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the link you're going through has a 404 error.
So you're not going to get any rss from that link.

Secondly, an RSS link ends with a `.rss` file most of the times.

> ex: http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss

Once you get an actual working RSS link, all you have to do is this:

```
fee = feedparser.parse('http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss')
for feed in fee.entries:
    print feed.title
    print feed.link
```

What I wrote above was for the getting the item elements.

Let me provide you with a better example.

```
import feedparser
rss_document = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Sample Feed</title>
<description>For documentation &lt;em&gt;only&lt;/em&gt;</description>
<link>http://example.org/</link>
<pubDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT</pubDate>
<!-- other elements omitted from this example -->
<item>
<title>First entry title</title>
<link>http://example.org/entry/3</link>
<description>Watch out for &lt;span style="background-image:
url(javascript:window.location='http://example.org/')"&gt;nasty
tricks&lt;/span&gt;</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 05 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT</pubDate>
<guid>http://example.org/entry/3</guid>
<!-- other elements omitted from this example -->
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
"""
rss = feedparser.parse(rss_document)

# Channel Details

print "-----Channel Details-----"

print rss.feed.title
print rss.feed.description
print rss.feed.link

# Item Details

print "-----Item Details-----"
for fee in rss.entries:
    print fee.title
    print fee.summary,
    print fee.link
```

Comment: You'll have to describe the problem a little more. I don't understand.
Give an example if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will give you all keys name,

```
import feedparser
feeds_all = feedparser.parse(URL)
feed_all_keys = feeds_all.keys()
feed_keys = feeds_all.feed.keys()
entries_keys = feeds_all.entries.keys()
```

1. feed_all_keys holds all keys
2. feed_keys holds keys related to feed
3. entries_keys holds keys related to entries(items)